# how can I add CSRF token in VUE or reqwest?

Tags: django, vue.js, csrf, reqwest

when I send data to server，the server get no response even do this 
if request.method == 'POST': 
    print("************request body*******")

in django views.py . thes code can't work.

```
enter code here

var app6 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-6',
  data: {
     realtimecost:0,
  },
  created() {            
        setInterval(() =>
        {
             this.realtimecost=this.realtimecost+1;           
             if(this.realtimecost==5)
                this.sendData();// here 

          }, 1000);
  },
  methods: {  
    sendData:function ()//send data
     {
        var self = this;
        reqwest({
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/',
        method:'post', 
        type:'json',
        headers: {
         "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken')
            },
        data:
        {
              realtimecost:5,
        },//end data
         success:function(resp){

         //self.getData()
         }//end success
        })//end reqwest
        },//end senddata

  }//end method

})//end app6
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: I have not used this http lib, but as I can see it's lacking of the interceptors, so you'll probably need to send csrf with the headers object in each request.
`headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token_here }` - pass this property to request object.

Comment: I added   headers: {  "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken')    }, but the server still get  no any response even do like this    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print("************request body*******")  cant works

Comment: Have you maybe changed csrf token header name, or you kept it as default ?

Comment: yes.  Cookies.get('csrftoken')    does'nt work.  does it relate to {% csrf_token %} in form?

Answer (score 0):

maybe I use {% csrf_token %}   at form in web body,  so "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken') can't work.

at last I place  "X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}' in headers and it works. but I don't know the mechanics of it.

```
reqwest({
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/',
        method:'post', 
        type:'json',
        headers: {
         "X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
```